# How to Import Data in .bson File

Tags: json, import, load, stata, bson

I would like to import the data found here: https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/crunching-30-years-of-nba-data-with-mongodb-aggregation/  (you can download the data towards the bottom in the Conclusion section).

The data comes in two files. First, a file called `games.metadata.json`. The complete contents is here:

```
{ "indexes" : [ { "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "nba.games", "name" : "_id_" } ] }
```

And the other file is called `games.bson`.

A sample of this file is:

```
@_idRÚüë›ΩuT
∫mÆboxd0´
players»    0‡ast   blkdrbfgfg3fg3_pctfg3afg_pct.533fgaftft_pct.750ftamp41:00orbpfplayerJeff Rulandptsstltovtrb1„astblkdrbfg    fg3fg3_pctfg3afg_pct.643fgaftft_pct.667ftamp36:00orbpfplayerCliff Robinsonptsstltovtrb2Êastblkdrbfgfg3fg3_pct.000fg3afg_pct.571fgaftft_pct1.000ftamp30:00orbpfplayer
Gus Williamsptsstltovtrb3‡astblkdrbfgfg3fg3_pctfg3afg_pct.533fgaftft_pct.667ftamp30:00orbpfplayerJeff Maloneptsstltovtrb4„astblkdrbfgfg3fg3_pctfg3afg_pct.250fgaftft_pct1.000ftamp25:00orbpfplayerCharles Jonesptsstltovtrb5„astblkdrbfgfg3fg3_pctfg3afg_pct.000fgaftft_pct.500ftamp26:00orbpfplayerDan Roundfieldptsstltovtrb6‡astblkdrbfgfg3fg3_pctfg3afg_pct.750fgaftft_pct1.000ftamp20:00orbpf
```

Any tips of how to get this into Stata?

Comment: I think you first need to convert the bson file to json. You can then read that into Stata with `insheetjson`. There are many scripts that can do the first available online. Just google "bson json converter" to find them.

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid you have to follow several steps

1. convert your data from bson to csv
2. export the csv
3. load the csv in Stata
4. do your stuff

In my experience `insheetjson` (Dimitri's nice suggestion) is awfulfy slow for mid sized datasets.