# Convert bson to json (then to csv or load json in Stata)

Tags: python, json, bson

As described in this post, [How to Import Data in .bson File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601138/how-to-import-data-in-bson-file?noredirect=1#comment68468455_40601138), I have a .bson file that I would like to somehow load into Stata.

The best case scenario would be to create a .csv file, but converting it to a .json file would also be great. Then I think I can use `insheetjson` in Stata.

I am familiar with python and found this post, [MongoDB: BSON to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439397/mongodb-bson-to-json?rq=1). The answer says that one can use the `simplejson` package and this code to convert bson to json:

```
result = db.mycol.find({ ....})
json = simplejson.dumps(result)
```

How can I get this to work? I don't exactly know how to load the bson file into python (which I think is what the `db` object is). I also don't know what should go in the parentheses `({ ....})`. Any suggestions? Again, another simple method to get the .bson data into a .csv or .json would also be welcome.

***Update

Taking the comment into advisement, I have done the following:

```
with open("filepath/games.bson", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

#note that we need to change to unicode because of errors with some characters
data2 = unicode(data, errors='ignore')

with open('filepath/games.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json.dump(data2, data_file)
```

But in both `data` and `data2`, I get a result that looks like:

```
\x00\x02fg_pct\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00.273\x00\x10fga\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x10ft\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02ft_pct\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00.500\x00\x10fta\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02mp\x00\x06\x00\x00\x0021:00\x00\x10orb\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10pf\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02player\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00Juan Dixon\x00\x10plus_minus\x00\xee\xff\xff\xff\x10pts\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x10stl\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10tov\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10trb\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x037\x00\xf7\x00\x00\x00\x10ast\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x10blk\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10drb\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x10fg\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10fg3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02fg3_pct\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00.000\x00\x10fg3a\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02fg_pct\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00.000\x00\x10fga\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x10ft\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02ft_pct\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00.500\x00\x10fta\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02mp\x00\x06\x00\x00\x0020:00\x00\x10orb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10pf\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02player
```

This doesn't seem to be what I want. If it is, I am not sure how to open it in Stata or another program.

Comment: In your example, I'm pretty sure that `result` would be a pure Python dict/list. If that's the case, you could simply use Python's standard `json` lib to do `json.dumps(result)` to have a JSON valid string or `json.dump(result)` to save your JSON to a file. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I have tried to do this and have updated the question with the results.

Comment: Try replacing `with open("filepath/games.bson", "r") as myfile:` with `with open("filepath/games.bson", "rb") as myfile:`

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately still get all the `\x00` and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import bson
with open('filepath/games.bson','rb') as f:
    data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I get this error: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'decode_all'"

Comment: Which version of python do you use? You didn't forget do import the bson module?

Comment: Version 2.7.10. I imported the bson module, yep.

Comment: I try it and it work. Maybe you uses any another object with the name bson?